# PouchDB Not Creating Database on Samsung Android Phones (Android v. 4.1.3, 4.2.2)

Tags: android, cordova, couchdb, pouchdb

I am creating a basic app for android devices. I am using normal Jade, JavaScript and PouchDB database. When I am deploying the app on simulator, Android devices like HTC, Tablet it is working fine but for Samsung Devices (Android v. 4.1.3, 4.2.2) it is not working.

My Jade code is

```
head

    script(src='../javascripts/pouchdb-nightly.min.js').
    script(type="text/javascript").
        var db = new PouchDB('pouchexample');

        function addBook(){
            var booktitle= window.document.bookform.titlefield.value;
            var authorfield= window.document.bookform.authorfield.value;
            var isbnfield= window.document.bookform.isbnfield.value;
            var book = {
                _id : isbnfield,
                title : booktitle,
                author : authorfield
            };
            db.put(book,function(err,res){
                if(!err){
                    clearField();
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
                        "new boook added";
                }
            });
        }

        function clearField() {
            window.document.bookform.titlefield.value="";
            window.document.bookform.authorfield.value="";
            window.document.bookform.isbnfield.value="";
        }

        function showBooks(){
            db.allDocs({include_docs:true, descending:true}, function(err, doc){
            showTableOfBooks(doc.rows);
            });
        }

        function showTableOfBooks(data){
            var div = document.getElementById("message");
            var str = "<table border='1' align='left'><tr><th>isbn</th><th>title</th><th>author</th></tr>";
            for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                str +="<tr><td>"+data[i].doc._id+"</td><td>"+data[i].doc.title+"</td><td>"+data[i].doc.author+"</td></tr>"
            }
            str+="</table> ";
            div.innerHTML = str;
        }

body
    form(name='bookform')
        | book title
        input(type='text', name='titlefield')
        br
        | book author
        input(type='text', name='authorfield')
        br
        | book isbn
        input(type='text', name='isbnfield')
        br
        input(type='button', value='add book', onclick='addBook()')
        br
        input(type='button', value='clear fields', onclick='clearFields()')
        br
        input(type='button', value='show book', onclick='showBooks()')
        #message
```

I downloaded "pouchdb-nightly.min.js" from http://download.pouchdb.com/pouchdb-nightly.min.js

Please tell me the appropriate solution for this problem.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There was [an issue with](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/issues/1207) certain android devices having an incomplete version of indexedDB, this this has been fixed in master so if you build a copy of pouchdb based on the master branch you should be fine.

Comment: This has since been fixed in an official release.  If you're using PouchDB 2.0.0+, you'll no longer see this issue, so e.g. you don't need the websql workaround that James D suggested.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, at first PouchDb was giving error: "can't find variable buffer" when I run it with React Native. Modification to pouchdb-binary-utils plugin to use the new buffer (safe-buffer installed by default with React-Native), solved the problem.

Get the updated plugin: https://github.com/emexrevolarter/react-native

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and *solved** it by forcing pouchdb to use websql.

```
var db = new PouchDB('websql://pouchexample');
```